# What is the best way to compare specific attributes from different lists in Java?

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, hashmap, compare

Trying to compare two attributes from two lists. I usually compare it iterating two lists and comparing each element (which I think is not optimal). Like:

```
list1.forEach(x -> {
    list2.forEach(y -> {
        if (x.getId().compareTo(y.getId()) == 0) 
            x.setMyAttribute(y.getNameAttribute());
    });
});
```

Is there a better way to compare a specific attribute from two lists? Still, I don't understand how to work with `HashMap`, but I want to know if is better use `HashMap` for this comparing and how to use it.

I guess I can create a `HashMap` only with `id` and `name` (attributes I need).

Comment: In your case, is `x.getId().compareTo(y.getId()) == 0` the same as `x.getId().equals(y.getId())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've shared is basically a brute-force solution, which checks every element in the `list2` for each element in the `list1`.

And you were thinking in the right direction. To avoid performing redundant iterations, you can index the contents of `list2` by generating a `HashMap` associating a particular element with its `id`.

I'll assume that the *natural order* of `id` is consistent with it `equals/hashCode` implementation, i.e. `(x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y))` because it's a recommended practice (and if you're using as `id` standard JDK classes like `Long`, `String`, `UUID` it would be the case).

That's how it might be implemented:

```
List<Foo> list1 = // initializing list1
List<Foo> list2 = // initializing list1
        
Map<ID, Foo> list2FoosById = list2.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Foo::getId,
        Function.identity(),
        (left, right) -> right // remove merge function if IDs are expected to be unique
    ));

for (Foo x : list1) {
    Foo y = list2FoosById.get(x.getId());                  // retrieving Foo from list2 with the corresponding ID
    if (y != null) x.setMyAttribute(y.getNameAttribute()); // reassign the attribute if the Foo having identical ID exists
}
```

Comment: Just what I need. I will accept the anwser. I did performance tests and the results were about 6 times lower in execution speed. Only last question, I don't understand what 'Function.identity(),
        (left, right) -> right ' should do

Comment: @Ad.Kh [`Function.identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html#identity()) simply returns what it receives as an input without changes. I.e. it's an equivalent of `i -> i`. And merge function of the collector `(left, right) -> right` will override the value with a new one (it can happen **only** if there might be several instances having the same `id` in the `list2`, and the code you've shared would work in the same way, I simply preserved this behavior).